# Which event I must use to detect when the value of a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn changes?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a `dataGridView` control with a  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column, the question is Which event of the dataGridView I must use to detect when the user change the selected value of a particular DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx). This event is raised when you leave the cell and it was modified.
The CellValueChanged occurs on the DataGridView, so you can look if the event was raised on the column index of your ComboBoxColumn.

Comment: The problem is that this event doesn't fire when the dropdown is selected.  It is only on lost focus.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx) event to fire off the [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) event. You can then manually ensure the value is set in the last event (though it will be set anyways). The MSDN example in the first link demonstrates this perfectly.